# ref_count in boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost

See the code below..
The last cout prints the use_count for p1 as 2 which is fine because p2 stores p1. Why does the use_count of p2 in last line also print 2? Should it not have been 1 because p2 is a shared pointer which stores only p1?

```
boost::shared_ptr<int> p1{new int{1}};
std::cout << *p1 << '\n';
std::cout << "--> " << p1.use_count() << "\n";
boost::shared_ptr<int> p2{p1};
std::cout << "--> " << p1.use_count() << " : " << p2.use_count() << "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

The use_count (and the managed pointer) is *shared* among the associated `shared_ptr`s. That makes it possible for the last `shared_ptr` to destroy the managed pointer when it's destroyed itself.

Note that the last `shared_ptr` might be `p1`, or `p2`. According to your understanding `p1` might destroy the managed object by mistake when it's destroyed, even `p2` still owns the object.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same because you are using the copy constructor to construct `p2` from `p1`. [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#copy_constructor) say if `p1` is not an empty `shared_ptr` then `p2` will share ownership with `p1`. So you have two `shared_ptr` instances `p1` and `p2` that *use* a single `int` pointer.

I think you are expecting `p1` an `p2` to point at different types. `use_count()` would be 1 for each if you used `boost::shared_ptr<boost::shared_ptr<int>> p2{p1};`

Answer (score 0):

> Should it not have been 1 because p2 is a shared pointer which stores only p1?

No. *This* is a shared_ptr that only stores p1:

```
boost::shared_ptr<boost::shared_ptr<int> > p2{new boost::shared_ptr<int>{p1}};
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/005be492ff29d8f8)</kbd>**

In other words, you discovered that shared pointers *share* the reference count. That's the whole purpose.